# How to insert an Array that contains Objects into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing database that has an important column that's called `InDays` with `nvarchar(150)` datatype.

In the existing data there's an `Array` that has an `Object` inside and looks like that:

```
InDays
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{ "day": 1, "from": "12:00am", "to": "2:00am"},{ "day": 4, "from": "2:00am", "to": "4:00am"}]
```

The `Objects` inside can be more than one.

I tried inserting it as it is, but i get `[object Object]` instead of the value.

EDIT--
The insert code.

```
DECLARE @InDays nvarchar(150) = [{ "day": 1, "from": "12:00am", "to": "2:00am"},{ "day": 4, "from": "2:00am", "to": "4:00am"}]

INSERT INTO Course (
        InDays
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @InDays
    )
```

Comment: can you please show the insert code ?

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future explorers

I simply had to convert the `JSON` format into a `String`.

Which is done by `JSON.stringify([{"value": value}])` then directly store it into the `sql database`

Then `JSON.parse("value")` to convert it to `JSON` again.

Answer (score 1):

> I have ... an important column that's ... nvarchar(150) datatype.

So use that type with your insert:

```
DECLARE @InDays nvarchar(150) = '[{ "day": 1, "from": "12:00am", "to": "2:00am"},{ "day": 4, "from": "2:00am", "to": "4:00am"}]'
```

Though I have my doubts 150 will be large enough if you could end up with many of these. Stepping through just the first object, assuming it's typical, you'll run out of space already at just the 5th member of the array.

Comment: I obviously need to map through this object later. will that be possible?

Comment: Possible, yes. But not at all simple unless you can use the new json types.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this?

Comment: Nope. My personal feeling is needing json in the db is poor schema design, and so I've managed to avoid doing it myself so far.

Comment: And do people usually do that ? storing an array that has multiple objects inside? i'm working at a project and found this existing already. it gets rendered in another application that i dont have access to its code.

Comment: Lots of people really like the json features. I'm just not one of them. Oh, and I should amend it to "needing queryable json". There are lots of good reasons to store json snippets in a database (CRMs, service logs, caches, etc). It's when you start using them as a crutch to avoid laying out real tables I get all snobby about it.